# Is applying temporary attributes to django models for use in views bad practice?

Tags: python, django

I'm working with a system for tracking employee hours, and need to calculate the year end information for those employees. In a separate section of our app, the previous dev iterated through the employees/employee tasks that have hours and created dictionaries to pass to the view for display. I've found that I can substantially cut the amount of code necessary to do this by applying 'temporary attributes' to the employees as I iterate through them then simply passing the employee queryset into the view, but is this bad practice and is there a better way to go about solving this problem? Heres a snippet for an example:

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class EmployeeTask(models.Model):
    emp = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    hours = models.FloatField()
```

views.py

```
def employee_report(request):
    employees = Employees.objects.all()
    tasks = EmployeeTask.objects.all()

    for employee in employees:
        emp_tasks = [task for task in tasks
                          if task.employee == employee]

        employee.total_hours = 0

        for emp_task in emp_tasks:
            employee.total_hours += emp_task.hours

    context = {
        'employees': employees
    }

    return render(request, 'app/employees.html', context)
```

I tried placing the logic in the model by creating a method that retrieved the employee tasks and did the calculation but that resulted in a massive amount of sql queries. Getting and matching the employees to tasks in the view was the only way I could find to avoid this. This method works, but I'm concerned it isnt necessarily the 'pythonic' (or 'djangonic' because that feels like a thing right now) way to go about it.

Note: I'm doing much more than this in the actual view, like filtering tasks based on type (paid time off, etc) and calculating the employee's use % from total company hours, all of which are added as temp attribute for the view but I am not including all of that here for the sake of brevity.

Comment: IMO that's a fine practice if the calculations aren't something you can express through an aggregation clause. I've done it frequently. I don't know of an authority or reference to cite other than my opinion, so I hesitate to give that as a definitive answer. But I think Python's "duck typing" approach fits with this. Your template doesn't care about whether it's iterating over a queryset or some other iterable, just that it is iterable.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I believe I tried using `select_related` but ran into an issue, will take another crack at it and see where it leads me. Thanks for pointing me in the direction of aggregation clauses, was not aware that existed!

Comment: Since one employee can have many tasks, you need to use `Employee.objects.prefetch_related('task')`. `select_related()` creates an inner join, so it only works if there is only one related `EmployeeTask` instance.

Comment: @knbk - right, thanks.

Comment: @wundunwundarwun - definitely do anything that you can in an aggregation clause, the db will be faster at it than Django. But sometimes you can't express the logic you need through aggregation, and in those cases iterating over the queryset and adding a temporary attribute is reasonable.

Comment: For this particular example you can use `Employee.objects.annotate(total_hours=models.Sum('task__hours'))`. You can have multiple annotations in a single query, but I'm not sure how well that translates to your actual use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not bad practice, and you can make it even better by putting it in your models, like this (untested but should give you the idea):

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    @property
    def total_hours(self):
        return self.task_set.all().aggregate(models.Sum('hours'))


class EmployeeTask(models.Model):
    emp = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    hours = models.FloatField()
```

Comment: You should use an aggregate query instead of summing like this. It will be much faster since the database will be in charge of the summing.

Comment: If I do it this way, wont that end up in a database query for each employee to retrieve their related tasks and result in significant slowdown when loading the view?

Comment: @wundunwundarwun Yes, it will do one additional query for each employee, but it shouldn't be too time consuming. Don't optimize prematurely. If you find it needs speeding up, you can use `select_related()` or `prefetch_related()` in the view.